# How to write a cron job for Heritrix3 web crawling?

Tags: java, web-crawler, heritrix

I build a job to crawl web data by Heritrix3.0. But it must run `Heritrix.java` as **Java application** and then the server was built. And I have to open the browser to type `https://localhost:8443` to build my job, then launch the job. Then unpause the job. How can I make a cron job for web crawling automatically? Please use Java language.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Any specific reason why you use Heritrix? Why not go for StormCrawler? It is in Java, runs continuously, can generate WARC files, is modular and pluggable, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I have this automated for my FYP. You can use Java but still according to `Heritrix` documentation the calls will be `CURLs` hence best, easiest and fastest would be to use `Shell` Scripts to invoke the `CURL` and get the task done.

Get Current Status of Engine:

```
curl -v -k -u admin:admin --anyauth --location -H "Accept: application/xml"
˓→https://localhost:8443/engine
```

Create new job for crawling in the Engine:

```
curl -v -d "createpath=myjob&action=create" -k -u admin:admin --anyauth --
˓→location \
-H "Accept: application/xml" https://localhost:8443/engine
```

Build the Job:

```
curl -v -d "action=build" -k -u admin:admin --anyauth --location -H "Accept:
˓→application/xml" https://localhost:8443/engine/job/myjob
```

Launch the Job:

```
curl -v -d "action=rescan" -k -u admin:admin --anyauth --location -H "Accept:
˓→application/xml" https://localhost:8443/engine
```